# Email alert for spark streaming delay

Tags: apache-spark, notifications

We have spark jobs that loads data from Kafka to hive database. Sometimes our streaming jobs getting too much data or hanged, causing delay in live streaming.
We can able to see the active process and pending process in queue  in Spark UI.

I want to consolidate these information and send an email alert in case of any delay.

Thanks

Comment: Typically you write a separate scheduled job that checks for data existence or pending tasks and fires alerts. The Spark job just processes things it sees, doesn't know its delayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use below GitHub package for Spark Email Alert.

https://github.com/NikhilSuthar/Scala-Spark-Mail